# Disable text highlighting when pasting using the mouse wheel in a terminal

Tags: command-line, mouse, copy-and-paste

I was testing the new Ubuntu 22.04 release and I noticed something really annoying:
When I highlight text anywhere and use the mouse wheel to paste it in a terminal window (any terminal) - the text remains highlighted after pasting it. Also, sometimes, whatever I've pasted isn't available in the BASH history (up arrow). I use this a lot to copy commands from articles to the terminal and it drives me nuts...

How can I revert to the way it works on 22.04?

A friend of mine told me it started happenning to him after he awitched from 22.04 to 21.10.

I am using X11 with the latest (510) nVidia driver.

Comment: Can you describe your expected behavior a bit more clearly? I've been using various Linux flavors since the late 90s and I don't remember pasting ever magically deselecting text in another window.

Comment: oooh, it's highlighted in the terminal where you paste it! I thought you meant it was still selected (highlighted) in the window from which you copied. Thanks @vanadium!